# How can I use NUnit to test label and buttons visibility?

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, mocking, nunit

I have a class that is used for logout from the website... I want to create a unit test for it, but the only thing (and only function) that it does is set a button and a label visibility to false and redirect the page

I created the [test] class, but I only can call the function (that does not return anything), I can't access the label and the button (I think because they were created inside the html page, and only the aspx.cs file can access them) to compare the visibility...

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by `i cant access the label and the button`? What is the error or behavior you experience? Please show the relevant code of your unit test and/or web page.

Comment: this is my code

        public void LogOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label.Visible = false;
            btLogOut.Visible = false;
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }

Label and btLogOut were created at aspx page with HTML code. In my test class

public class TestPage
{  
    [Test]  
    public void Test_logOut()  
    {  

        Page pae = new Page();
        //here I can only access the method LogOut(), and i cant check the value of the label and button from here

or is this an example of method that you shouldt test with unit test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can look at is an integration test using a tool like Selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), rather than a unit test. Selenium can be 'driven' from within an nunit test. That way you actually start up a browser, go and click a button on it, and check the results.

Other than that, you could try moving the code out of the code-behind file and into a simple c# class that you can test directly with a unit test. Then you will just make calls to an instance of the simple c# class from within you Page object.